# Session start query

Tags: php

can anyone tell me why when i use this set of codes for my login page.., every time the first login it will automatically refresh at the same login html page and when i do the same login attempt(second time) with the same password and all it then redirect user to the mainpage. In other words.. why does this session start codes always affect my first login attempt.

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['user']!= null && $_SESSION['id']!=null && $_SESSION['mail']!=null){
    $name = $_SESSION['user'];
    $idt = $_SESSION['id'];
    $email = $_SESSION['mail'];
}
else{
    $idt = null;
    $email = null;
    $name = null;
    echo '<script>window.location.href="users.html"</script>';
}
```

Comment: For sure, its not the problem with your user verification page, but has to do something with your login/validation page.

Comment: It sounds like those session values either are or are not set when you expect them to be.  Where do you set them?  Can you provide a more complete example?

Answer (score 0):

In this script or some where else you should write the code of setting session, and then redirect user on this page.

once session is set user is logged in and if not then user will be redirected.

Lets say there is a for of login on the same page.

e.g.

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if($_POST) {
          $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
          $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
          $_SESSION['mail'] = $_POST['mail'];
    }

    if ($_SESSION['user']!= null && $_SESSION['id']!=null && $_SESSION['mail']!=null){
        $name = $_SESSION['user'];
        $idt = $_SESSION['id'];
        $email = $_SESSION['mail'];
    }
    else{
        $idt = null;
        $email = null;
        $name = null;
        echo '<script>window.location.href="users.html"</script>';
    }
```

Then your page should work.

Thanks
Amit